# How many sich's can one sentence have?

Tags: word-usage

This sentence appears in Anthony Doerr's Alles Licht, das wir nicht sehen, Aus dem Englischen von Werner Löcher-Lawrence:

> Heute ist ein schöner Tag, ein Tag, an den es **sich** zu erinnern lohnt.

DWDS says sich is optional with lohnen, but manditory for this meaning of erinnern. So if a sentence uses 2 reflexive verbs, can it have 2 sich's?

> Heute ist ein schöner Tag, ein Tag, **sich** an den es **sich** zu erinnern lohnt.

And what is the meaning of the "sich sich", that I am finding so plentifully [in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=sich%20sich&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=10)?

Comment: "An sich ist heute ein schöner Tag, an den es sich sich zu erinnern lohnt, es sei denn, man hat sich verletzt." Potentially you can have an infinite amount of *sich*s in a sentence.

Comment: The vast majority of the "sich sich" corpus entries are simple typos (accidental word duplications). Occasionally the first "sich" is a misspelling (or mis-scan?) of "sie" ("daß **sie** sich als Bürger Finnlands fühlen"). Only  a tiny fraction are correct (Fernliebe *an sich* lässt sich einkapseln).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sentence is wrong but the answer to you question is still: Yes, one sentence can have two "sich". Your example would in that case be:

> Heute ist ein schöner Tag, ein Tag, an den es sich sich zu erinnern lohnt

Usually one would try to not do this and use a separate sub clause:

> Heute ist ein schöner Tag, ein Tag, an den es sich lohnt, sich zu erinnern

Regarding your second question: Most of the examples on the linked pages are simple typos and usually should be "sie sich" or "sich sie"... this is a common mistake when typing these two words. Others are simply wrong duplications of "sich":

Sie sich:

> **Wrong:**
> Sie muß Namen und Anschrift des Betroffenen, gegen den **sich** sich richtet, und die Rufnummer oder eine andere Kennung seines Telekommunikationsanschlusses enthalten.
> **Correct:** Sie muß Namen und Anschrift des Betroffenen, gegen den **sie** sich richtet, und die Rufnummer oder eine andere Kennung seines Telekommunikationsanschlusses enthalten.

Duplicate sich:

> **Wrong:** War irre freundlich, hat **sich** sich die ganze Zeit bedankt.
> **Correct:** War irre freundlich, hat sich die ganze Zeit bedankt.

Comment: Two *sich*s are generally bad style, but I would avoid two consecutive *sich*s by rephrasing the sentence as *Heute ist ein schöner Tag, ein Tag, an den es sich zu erinnern  sich lohnt.*

Comment: I would put that as *… an den sich zu erinnern es sich lohnt.*

Comment: I'd simply omit one *sich: ... an den es sich zu erinnern lohnt.* I understand it's ungrammatical (I may be influenced by living with an American). But to me it surely is better than double *sich.* Edit: Actually, [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/lohnen) lists the reflexive pronoun as optional, so a single *sich* is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Heute ist ein schöner Tag, an dem es sich lohnt, sich ans sich erinnern zu erinnern.